# How do you yank between two different symbols in vim?

Tags: vim

Given I have:

```
"foo === BAR.BAZ"
```

If my cursor is in the middle of the string I want to yank (say `'R'`, in this case), and I want to yank all of `BAR.BAZ`, how would I do that easily?

I can't just use `yiw` because it breaks on the `.`. I need to yank between `<space>` and `"`

This is just one example. I realize that there are ways to make vim yank words separated by periods, but I'm looking for a more general solution for cases that involve more complex symbols.

Something like `"yank between <first_occurrence_of_left_symbol> <first_occurrence_of_right_symbol>"`

Which in the above case would be:

`yb<space>"`

Comment: I can see the rudiments of how this could work: mark current location, F<left symbol>, mark current location, return to first mark, f<right symbol>, y`<second mark>, clear marks.  You'd have to wrap that up in a function or something that could await the input of the two symbols, then run.  That's the part with which I have less experience.

Comment: Why not just use the inbuilt text objects ? yiW does what you need in this case, for other cases there are other text objects.

Answer (score 5):

You can define your own text object like this:

```
onoremap I :exec 'norm vT'.nr2char(getchar()).'ot'.nr2char(getchar())<cr>
```

Then, to do your example, you would type

```
yI<space>"
```

The mnemonic I think of is "(d)elete (I)nbetween `<char 1>`, `<char 2>`". Thankfully, `I` cannot be used as an argument to an operator, so this doesn't override anything. Of course, you can pick a different key if it would be more intuitive to you.

The convenient thing about doing this as an `onoremap` mapping, is that this gives you the ability to use *any* operator on that text. So `d`, `c`, `gu`, `y`, and many others will work just fine.

While you're at it, you can add a mapping for *around* two characters also, it's a trivial modification:

```
onoremap A :exec 'norm vF'.nr2char(getchar()).'of'.nr2char(getchar())<cr>
```

Comment: I really like this answer, but it has one problem: it can be tricked if `<char 2>` appears between the cursor and the left end.  E.g., on the string `BARZ.BAZ`, if the cursor is on the second `B` and you say `yIBZ`, then you yank `AR`, not `ARZ.BA`.

Comment: @Wolf Good point! I've edited my answer, does that version work better?